# What is causing hard drive grinding?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance

My windows (XP) hard drive grinds a lot and it negatively affects the performance of other applications.

I have plenty of RAM and have already verified that this hard drive activity is not page file swap activity.  I have also already looked in task manager to see if only one or two processes are active but I have found no smoking gun.

What tools can I use to directly determine what application or feature of the OS is causing the hard drive activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  Make sure you show the columns that contain the I/O activity.

Sometimes you may see a process running multiple services that causes the activity.  In that case, it requires a bit of guesswork.

Comment: OMG - In my case it was Razer gamescannerservice...WTH!

Answer (score 3):

If the sound is new (i.e. a change from the past) it may indicate a worn bearing or other mechanical problem with the drive.

In that case, run-don't-walk to obtain a new drive and a transfer everything over pronto. The time to total failure from the onset of symptoms is not predictable.

---

Jeff's point is well taken. Not being a windows person, I don't know the tools, but other posters seem to have that well in hand. Here is a heuristic: If you can generate this behavior on an otherwise quiescent system by opening a medium sized document in notepad, you should be very worried indeed.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP was referring to (I think he meant regular, heavy hard drive activity). But it is true -- ANY unusual sounds from a hard drive mean you should PANIC and start backing up **immediately**

Comment: And while you're running to the store to get the new hard drive, you could run smartmontools (http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) to see if there's actually a problem with the drive.  I watched one drive "rot" right in front of me - every day, there were a few more bad sectors.  One day, it just wouldn't boot any more.  (I had a replacement ready, but was curios as to how long it would last - it was just my boot disk, so there wasn't anything important on it.)

Answer (score 2):

SysInternals **[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)** is a tool that can monitor HDD activity in real-time, showing you what files are being accessed. Be warned though, it can be a bit of a firehose and can take a bit of practice to get the hang of.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx) to see what drive activity is going on.  It shows you both which programs are to blame and which files are involved.

Generally, all the tools from [Sysinternals](http://www.sysinternals.com/) are great.  I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) often.

Comment: Actually, DiskMon does *not* show process information (or file-system level information). *[FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642)* does.