# Clicking/Croaking Noise coming from computer

Tags: noise, clicking-sound

My laptop (a HP Compaq 6735s) is about 1 year old and has recently started making funny clicking/croaking noises. The noise happens a lot when I turn the laptop on and now and again while the computer is turned on. My hard drive is manufactured by toshiba. Does this clicking noise mean  my computer is about to die and if so is there anything I can do? A link to an mp3 recording of the sound is underneath. Thanks in advance

[The clicking noise](http://218751827087933317-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/computerclick1/clicks/click.mp3?attachauth=ANoY7conZ5FvEe9It3z0gg_385KO_qw92hoqFmFym4gLJSAtQPiaoH2Uuuz7w6rpWnG8JIiW6-cqUZUMUfECcYEq_NoKk6gbMBaRS-5GxXDrk2N-fCKke--D2LgKXhSnZlHwxpIWZU0d4J_D776GD5w_6KMrJMPEHjul5VBBmk4rD24VF0nHdlXPZ7q_MaFMu_4j6Dqw-nf-ApBuc-sBiFz-znegUwTFkw%3D%3D&attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/13192/what-is-causing-hard-drive-grinding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a hardware expert, this is my opinion and what I'd do if this would be my laptop!*

First things first: back up your data!

After that, the sound reminds me of the noise a harddisk *can* make, especially my old ones sounded similar to that. On the other hand, it could also be a fan noise, like a small piece  of paper which is floating around and sometimes touching the fan.

To test this out, stresstest the harddisk, if the clicking noise appears at that, it's the drive. Otherwise you could do the same with the CPU, maybe it's something with the fan, which only shows on high rpms (like the fan being out of balance).

If you still have warranty on it, turn it in.

Comment: +1. I think it's probably the fan, but you've said pretty much what I wanted to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will backup my data and hope the computer stays OK