# How do I open Resource Monitor on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

When I press the `Windows` key and type `Resource Monitor`, no programs are shown. How do I open "Resource Monitor" on Windows 8?

Comment: You could just type in resmon, works in both the run dialog and in the start menu search, without having to enable Administrative Tools.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make the Resource Monitor and other administrative tools show up on the start screen, open the charms bar (<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or swipe from right) and click **Settings**. Under "tiles", turn on **Show Administrative Tools**.

If you want to have the tools available to search, but don't want them all to show up on the start screen, you can subsequently unpin all of the tools that you don't want permanently on the start screen.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. It's simple, reveals a hidden feature (silly on MS's part), and gives access to other tools that SuperUsers would no doubt be looking for.

Comment: Thanks @probackpacker. Based on your username, I'm going to ask, have you seen http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Note that you must begin on the Start screen. There is a different Settings menu for the Desktop.

Answer (score 15):

There is no Start Screen shortcut to "Resource Monitor" by default in Windows 8, but you can create one:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to show the desktop.
2. Right-click in an empty area, choose **New** → **Shortcut**.
3. In **Type the location of the item**, type `perfmon.exe /res`; click **Next**.
4. In **Type a name for this shortcut**, type `Resource Monitor`; click **Finish**.

You should now have a shortcut on the desktop named "Resource Monitor". Right-click on this shortcut and choose **Pin to Start**.

Now, when you press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and type `Resource Monitor`, an icon that launches Resource Monitor should appear on the Start Screen.

Answer (score 13):

Another approach would be as follows:-

1. Open the Task Manager:

   - Right Click on your taskbar, and click on "Task Manager"
   - Or, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. Head over to the Performance tab.
3. Click on "Open Resource Monitor" at the bottom.

[image: A link to the Resource Moniter.]

Answer (score 1):

I used Shail's approach. Then on the taskbar, you can right-click and "pin to taskbar".
After that you can right-click the pinned item, then right-click on name of pinned item, then select properties to change the "shortcut" properties of the pinned icon. Under the shortcut tab, add **/res** after perfmon.exe in the Target textbox. Now you will have a pinned icon that works correctly.
I'm amazed that Microsoft does not do this correctly in the first place when you pin the running app.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>windows key</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> > opens run command.

Type `resmon` and it will open resource monitor.

Next time just typing `re` or `res` it will work; it will have `resmon` as a suggestion. I open my calculator in the same way almost 20 times a day.

If you are really adamant on having a shortcut you can open resource monitor using above method and then right-click on the icon on the taskbar and select **pin this program to taskbar** and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut to Resource Monitor:

Windows 8, click Desktop Icon then press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, then type `perfmon.exe /res` to run it.

Another way to get to all your admin tools is <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> > Control Panel > Administrative Tools