# How to stop constant bandwidth usage in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

When I'm doing anything bandwidth is being used. I think Windows 8 is using the bandwidth (constant download and upload). When I disconnect the Internet and again connect to the internet, the bandwidth consumption resumes.

Is there any way I could stop the usage? How do I see what is constantly using this bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows' in-built [Resource Monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/512724/how-do-i-open-resource-monitor-on-windows-8) to see what's using your networking (etc.).

[image]